# JSF ui:debug causing NullPointerException

Tags: jsf-2, flash-scope

My JSF application has a `<ui:debug>` tag in the top level template.  I have a data item creation page that saves the item to the DB.  The DB then returns the saved item which I store in the JSF flash.  I then redirect to a new page and display the item that I retrieved from the flash.  When I view the page, the Debug page is shown with a `NullPointerException` and sometimes there is no stack trace and other times there is a stacktrace similar to (don't pay attention to the specific line numbers.

```
NullPointerException
at com.sun.facelets.util.DevTools.writeVariables(DevTools.java:158)
at com.sun.facelets.util.DevTools.writeVariables(DevTools.java:144)
at com.sun.facelets.util.DevTools.debugHtml(DevTools.java:135)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.UIDebug.writeDebugOutput(UIDebug.java:92)
at com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.UIDebug.encodeBegin(UIDebug.java:81)
...
```

If I remove the `<ui:debug>` tag, then my page is successfully displayed.  What is causing the NullPointerException?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the job of the `<ui:debug>` tag is to display the contents of all the various JSF scopes including the "flash scope".  `DevTools.writeVariables` is a helper function that is used to turn the objects in the scopes into something readable to display in the debug page.  It uses methods like `toString()` to display the objects.  The object that was stored in the flash, overrode the `toString()` method with the following boilerplate code

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  //TODO: Supply implementation
  return null
}
```

Since the `toString()` was returning null, it later caused a `NullPointerException`.  If you properly implement `toString()`, this error will not occur.